# sublime text 2: view find/search history

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there a way to view the find/search history in Sublime Text 2?

In eclipse there is such a feature, see screenshot below. I'd expect something similar in sublime text 2.

[image: eclipse "show previous searches" feature]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be the same in ST2, but in ST3 you can put your cursor in the `Find` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) search field, and hitting the <kbd>­­↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow keys should scroll through the search history.

Comment: That's pretty neat. Seems to also work on each fields of the `"find in folder"` form http://i.imgur.com/yI2cXPr.png , the fields being "find" "where" & "replace"

Answer (score 6):

You can also view the entire raw history (of searches, file/folder paths and more)

Open the file `Session.sublime-session` and search for `find_history`

On Mac OSX: 
`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session`

On Windows, I'm not exactly sure but probably something like:
 
`%AppData%\Sublime Text 3\Options\Session.sublime-session`

Answer (score 3):

AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local\Session.sublime_session